# c# - Share project with libraries

Tags: c#

I installed libraries in my project (Microsoft.Speech, Microsoft.Speech.Recognition, speeches Brazilian), on my computer they work perfectly, but on other computers do not work because they do not have the library installed.
Is there any method I include the DLL's in my project and share it with them? And include the speeches?
Without the need for them to install the library?

I've used the Google Translate.

Comment: Create an installer, or copy all the files in the bin to the new computer.

Comment: @paqogomez: So, without an installer means with an installer? OP, you mostly just need to make sure the references are set to copy to output I think. Then copying the whole folder should work.

Comment: @Magus, I took `install the library` to mean install separately from the application.  Your point on copy to output is a good one however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Project Properties > Resources > Add Resource > Add Existing File

Do that for each dll you need, and rebuild. Hope that helps.